# Select data from the list and display it in the listBox, C#

Tags: c#, linq, listbox

So, I have made this class for the employees, now I need to select from the list, for example all developers aged 25 or older and let's say, order them by name also, to show up in my listBox that I created. Didn't succeeded so far, I understand that I must use Linq, and write something like

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var query = Employee.Where(Employee => employee.Age > 25);
}
```

But it gives me error for Where, it doesn't recognize the syntax. Also, I can't figure out how to select the other data.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", Name, Age);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Employee> personList = new List<Employee>()
        {
                new Employee(){ Name="Steve", Age =23, Position="Developer"},
                new Employee(){ Name="Mark", Age =32, Position="Designer"},
                new Employee(){ Name="Bill", Age =23, Position="Developer"},
                new Employee(){ Name="Nill", Age =25, Position="Analyst"},
                new Employee(){ Name="Kevin", Age =28, Position="Analyst"},
                new Employee(){ Name="Steve", Age =22, Position="Designer"}
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I think **Employee** term in the lambda expression is match to the class name. Change it to **emp**, but it's not only one issue. In your sample I see mixed apps: Console and Desktop (Web). The best advice for you is to get understanding what is LINQ and *where* and *how* you can use it

Comment: For starters, change `Employee` to `employee` or vice versa in your query so the names match...

Comment: "But it gives me error for Where, it doesn't recognize the syntax. Also, I can't figure out how to select the other data." Don't you think you need first to learn the syntax before using it? What you are asking is pretty basic.

Comment: It would also help if you queried the collection and not the class.

Comment: `var query = Employee.Where(Employee => employee.Age > 25);` the lambda expression is same with the class name. you can change to `var query = Employee.Where(emp => emp.Age > 25);` to order by name you can add `.OrderBy(emp => emp.Name)`

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm asking for help here, I got a basic view on the syntax, but I don't get how I should implement it, I'm new to C#

Comment: Then start from here [Basic LINQ Query Operations (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you want to select particular fields of your collection you should write like this:

```
personList
   .Where(x => x.Age > 25) //This is where your conditions should be
   .OrderBy(x => x.Name) //That's how you order your collection
   .Select(x => new //And that's the part where you select your fields
   { 
      Text = x.Name, 
      Age = x.Age
   });
```

Basically with this kind of select you creating anonymous object.

But to fill select list you should create not anonymous object but particular enumeration and you also can do it with linQ:

```
personList
   .Where(x => x.Age > 25) 
   .Select(x => new ListItem //note that here you create ListItem
   { 
      Text = x.Name, 
      Value = x.Age
   });
```